# Pandas: how to find names from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two datframes `df1` and `df2`. `df1` contains the relationships between two IDs while df2 contains the name of the IDs.

```
df1  ID1  ID2
0     0    2
1     1    3
2     3    2
3     1    2


df2   ID  name
0     0   John
1     1   Carl 
2     2   Eva
3     3   Julia
```

I would like to add the name information to `df1`, such as:

```
df1  ID1  ID2   name1   name2 
0     0    2    John     Eva
1     1    3    Carl     Julia
2     3    2    Julia    Eva
3     1    2    Carl     Eva
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
s = df2.set_index('ID')['name']
df1['name1'] = df1['ID1'].map(s)
df1['name2'] = df1['ID2'].map(s)
```

Alternative:

```
df1 = df1.assign(name1=df1['ID1'].map(s), name2=df1['ID2'].map(s))
```

---

```
print (df1)
   df1  ID1  ID2  name1  name2
0    0    0    2   John    Eva
1    1    1    3   Carl  Julia
2    2    3    2  Julia    Eva
3    3    1    2   Carl    Eva
```

Comment: I received the following error: `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only with uniquely valued Index Object`

Comment: @emax - it means there is duplicated `ID` in `df1`. Check it by `df2[df2['ID'].duplicated(keep=False)]`. Do you need drop all duplicated ?

Comment: If want remove duplicates `s = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID']).set_index('ID')['name']` is necessary

Comment: @emax - Super, nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no common values other than index

you can try [concat function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.concat.html)

```
pd.concat([df1, df2],axis =0)
```